# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to make a OneToMany relationship between User and Project but I am getting following error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ProjectDTO.FKUser in UserDTO.projectDTOs
```

My User class look like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserDTO implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer iduser;
    private Set<ProjectDTO> projects = new HashSet<ProjectDTO>(0);;

    public UserDTO() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "IDUser", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIduser() {
        return this.iduser;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "FKUser")
    public Set<ProjectDTO> getProjectDTOs() {
        return projects;
    }

}
```

And my Project class looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class ProjectDTO implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idproject;
    private UserDTO FKUser;

    public ProjectDTO() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "IDProject", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdproject() {
        return this.idproject;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FKUser", referencedColumnName = "IDUser")
    public UserDTO getUserDTO() {
        return FKUser;
    } 
}
```

I went through some similar questions but I was unable to figure out where I was going wrong. Maybe I am missing something very obvious.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `mappedBy` you must use field name (or part of the getter name without `get` for property-based access), not column name.

```
    //...    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userDTO")
    public Set<ProjectDTO> getProjectDTOs() {
        return projects;
    }
    //...
```

Note: also need to add setters.

Comment: oh I had to do userDTO instead of UserDTO. Why is that though?

Comment: If field is called `name` then getter for this field will `getName()`

Answer (score 1):

mappedBy needs to point to the entity that does the mapping, so I believe it should be mappedBy="USER"